# How do I get three finger click to work on my touchpad? (middle click works with laser/optical mouse)

Tags: mouse, touchpad, laptop, multi-touch, synaptics

Running Ubuntu 15.10 on a 4 year old laptop, and while the touchpad driver I'm using works very well with scrolling and two finger clicking, I cannot figure out how to get three finger clicking to work at all. I've searched a lot, and I've only found ways to switch the two finger click function (right click, which works for me) and the three finger click function (intended middle click function, does not work at all), however this doesn't work because my three finger click seems to have no action assigned to it whatsoever. Middle clicking does work when using an external mouse, so I think it has to do with the touchpad driver.